# Change default font color for of bbpress tinymce forum submission textarea

Tags: fonts, filter, tinymce, bbpress

So after I found that altering content.css from the tinymce plugin folder didn't work I tried the content_css routine by adding a filter to functions.php:

```
function tinymce_other_css_for_content( $init ) {
$init['content_css'] = get_bloginfo('stylesheet_url') . "customtinymce.css";
return $init;
}

add_filter('tiny_mce_before_init', 'tinymce_other_css_for_content');
```

and added

```
body#tinymce.mceContentBody.bbp_reply_content.post-type-topic.wp-editor{
   color: red !important; /* FF requires a important here */
}
```

to customtinymce.css and placed it in my theme root.

Didn't work, is there something I'm doing wrong?

Thanks in advance.

P.S. I'm also looking for a solution that only colors the textarea for the forums, not the WP admin dashboard.

Comment: can you show us a live example? i guess there is somehting wrong with the url of your css - because content_css is the correct way to go here

Comment: http://www.worldsfactory.net/dev/forums/topic/auto-draft/

For some reason my changes are working now.  They seem take a very long time to take effect.  A period of hours.  What I have there now was a test.  Any idea why that might be?

Comment: maybe becasue of some sort of caching (client or server-sided), can't tell from here without knowledge of the systems involved and their configuration

Comment: Turns out it was just my browser caching, even though I had been doing a hard reload.

Comment: ok, that's 2what i thought - i will post this as answer, so you may accept it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Might be because of some sort of caching (client or server-sided), can't tell from here without knowledge of the systems involved and their configuration